# NoMethodError: undefined method `unsafe_load' for Psych:Module (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, internationalization

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku. For some reason, the app crashed and running rails console into the heroku console gives this error although the app is not multilingual, so no use of I18n at all.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:241:in `load_yml'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:245:in `rescue in load_yml': can not load translations from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `unsafe_load' for Psych:Module (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)
```

I don't get such an error on localhost, only on Heroku.

Comment: ActiveRecord uses externalised strings even for English, so you get some level of i18n no matter what. Can you check the Heroku log and see what version of `psych` gem it is using?

Comment: thanks for the reply! Here is what I get by running `gem list psych`
 => 
`psych (4.0.1, default: 3.1.0, 2.2.4)`

Comment: I ran into this locally using spree 4.2.5 and psych 3.1.0.  If I remove `Gemfile.lock` and regenerate, I _do_ get this error.  However, if I just update the lockfile using `bundle install`, it works.  I have no idea why.  Comparing the lockfiles, rails goes from 6.1.4 to 6.1.4.1, so maybe that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in my installation, the difference between the working `Gemfile.lock` and non-working, is the version of `bootsnap`:

```
--- Gemfile.lock        2021-08-26 23:12:52.090787013 -0400
+++ Gemfile.lock.bad    2021-08-26 23:07:36.116432150 -0400
@@ -198,7 +198,7 @@
       aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
     bcrypt (3.1.16)
     bindex (0.8.1)
-    bootsnap (1.7.7)
+    bootsnap (1.8.0)
       msgpack (~> 1.0)
     bootstrap (4.6.0)
       autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
```

There must be an incompatibility buried somewhere in the dependencies of that gem.  That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The issue is solved!

Answer (score 2):

bootsnap 1.8.1 has just been released with a fix

https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/commit/1d14e2582412e5a982c895638c26278281b01cff

https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/releases/tag/v1.8.1

So, changing your `Gemfile` to

```rb
gem "bootsnap", "~> 1.8.1"
```

and running

```
bundle update bootsnap
```

should fix the issue

Comment: I can confirm that requiring `bootsnap ~> 1.8.1` does fix the problem.